# SSAS Error Aggregate member calculate "the member and level in a date conversion function must belong to the same hierarchy"

Tags: aggregate, ssas

I try to aggregate the Net Amount between two hierarchies, Dimtime and Hierarchy Season not related.

I use this script but it shows this errore: "the member and level  in a date conversion function must belong to the same hierarchy. Could you help me?

Aggregate( PeriodsToDate([Dim Time].[Date YSQMD].[Year],
ParallelPeriod(
[Season].[Hierarchy Season].[Anno Di Vendita], 1, [Season].[Hierarchy Season].CurrentMember ) )
,  [Measures].[Net Amount]